# Table resizing Issues

Tags: tables

[image]

This table is not properly showing in the center. I want to make it in the center. Kindly help me with this.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Resistances & Rated Voltages & Currents & Losses & Input Output Power & Efficeicny \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Rsh=40 ohm\\ Ra= 10 ohms\end{tabular} &
  Vt=88V &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It=5A\\ Ish=2.2A\\ Ia=2.8V\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shunt Field Losses=193.6W\\ Armature Losses=78.4W\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pin=440W\\ Pout=168W\end{tabular} &
  38.18\% \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Rsh=40ohms\\ Ra= 10 ohms\end{tabular} &
  Vt=88V &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It=7A\\ Ish=2.2A\\ Ia=4.8A\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shunt Field Losses=193.6W\\ Armature Losses=230.4W\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pin=616W\\ Pout=192W\end{tabular} &
  31.16\% \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Rsh=40ohms\\ Ra= 10 ohms\end{tabular} &
  Vt=88V &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It=9A\\ Ish=2.2A\\ Ia=6.8A\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shunt Field Losses=193.6W\\ Armature Losses=468.4W\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pin=792W\\ Pout=130W\end{tabular} &
  16.4 \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Rsh=40 ohms\\ Ra= 10 ohms\end{tabular} &
  Vt=88V &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It=10A\\ Ish=2.2A\\ Ia=7.8A\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shunt Field Losses=193.6W\\ Armature Losses=608.4W\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pin=880W\\ Pout=78.4W\end{tabular} &
  8.9\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Could you please post a compilable code? We don't even know the document class you use.

Comment: I'm using \documentclass{report}

Comment: Isn’t the problem basically that the table is to wide and extends over the right margin? If you want to avoid that, I suggest you actually use one X column and p-type columns with lower width to fit everything on the page.

Comment: You could ave a lot of space by avoiding repetition. Since all rows contain the same contents, you could get rid of the first two columns and place this information in the caption of the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is the redundant repeated information.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
 @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
 S[table-format=2.0]
 S[table-format=2.0]
 S[table-format=2.0]
 S[table-format=2.0]
 S[table-format=1.1]
 S[table-format=1.1]
 S[table-format=3.1]
 S[table-format=3.1]
 S[table-format=3.0]
 S[table-format=3.1]
 S[table-format=2.2]
 @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Resistances} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\splitcell{Rated \\ Voltages}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Currents} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Losses} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\splitcell{Input Output \\ Power}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Efficiency} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(\si{\ohm})} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(\si{\volt})} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(\si{\ampere})} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(\si{\watt})} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(\si{\watt})} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(\%)} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-3} \cmidrule{4-6}
\cmidrule{7-8} \cmidrule{9-10}
{Rsh} & {Ra} & {Vt} & {It} & {Ish} & {Ia} & {SFL} & {AL} & {Pin} & {Pout} & \\
\midrule
40 & 10 & 88 &  5 & 2.2 & 2.8 & 193.6 &  78.4 & 440 & 168   & 38.18 \\
40 & 10 & 88 &  7 & 2.2 & 4.8 & 193.6 & 230.4 & 616 & 192   & 31.16 \\
40 & 10 & 88 &  9 & 2.2 & 6.8 & 193.6 & 468.4 & 792 & 130   & 16.4  \\
40 & 10 & 88 & 10 & 2.2 & 7.8 & 193.6 & 608.4 & 880 &  78.4 &  8.9  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{11}{@{}l@{}}{SFL: Shunt field losses; AL: Armature losses}
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egerg. You did it in best form.

Answer (score 3):

(1) Change the left margin to make the table fit in the page

(2) Use two lines headings with the help of the package `makecell`.

As added bonus, not related with your question, expand the cells vertically.

(3) Recommended: use the package `siunitx` to insert the units in a consistent way and according the standard. I only did the first line.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm]{geometry} % set margins

\usepackage{makecell} 

\usepackage{showframe} %show the margins

\renewcommand\theadalign{cc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[6pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\usepackage{siunitx} % proper units 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \thead{Resistances} & \thead{Rated \\ Voltages} & \thead{Currents} & \thead{Losses} & \thead{Input  Output\\ Power} & \thead{Efficiency} \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Rsh=\SI{40}{\ohm}\\ Ra=\SI{10}{\ohm}\end{tabular} &
        Vt=\SI{88}{\volt} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It=\SI{5}{\ampere}\\ Ish=\SI{2.2}{\ampere}\\ Ia=\SI{2.8}{\ampere}\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shunt Field Losses=\SI{193.6}{\watt}\\ Armature Losses= \SI{78.4}{\watt}\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pin=\SI{440}{\watt}\\ Pout=\SI{168}{\watt}\end{tabular} &
        38.18\% \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Rsh=40 ohms\\ Ra= 10 ohms\end{tabular} &
        Vt=88V &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It=7A\\ Ish=2.2A\\ Ia=4.8A\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shunt Field Losses=193.6W\\ Armature Losses=230.4W\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pin=616W\\ Pout=192W\end{tabular} &
        31.16\% \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Rsh=40 ohms\\ Ra= 10 ohms\end{tabular} &
        Vt=88V &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It=9A\\ Ish=2.2A\\ Ia=6.8A\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shunt Field Losses=193.6W\\ Armature Losses=468.4W\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pin=792W\\ Pout=130W\end{tabular} &
        16.40\% \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Rsh=40 ohms\\ Ra= 10 ohms\end{tabular} &
        Vt=88V &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It=10A\\ Ish=2.2A\\ Ia=7.8A\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shunt Field Losses=193.6W\\ Armature Losses=608.4W\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pin=880W\\ Pout=78.4W\end{tabular} &
        8.90\% \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Simon Dispa